# extract lines between question and answer

Tags: python, regex

```
Question No. 01 
Which of the following has more fire resisting characteristics? 
(A) Marble 
(B) Lime stone 
(C) Compact sand stone 
(D) Granite 
Answer: Option C 

Question No. 02 
The rocks which are formed due to cooling of magma at a considerable depth from earth's surface are called 
(A) Plutonic rocks 
(B) Hypabyssal rocks 
(C) Volcanic rocks 
(D) Igneous rocks 
Answer: Option A 

Question No. 03 
Plywood has the advantage of 
(A) Greater tensile strength in longer direction 
(B) Greater tensile strength in shorter direction 
(C) Same tensile strength in all directions 
(D) None of the above Answer: Option C
```

I have tried to extract question between Question No. \d+ and Answer: Option 
in a list format

```
with open('Building materials.txt','r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        if re.search('Question No. (\d+)',line):
            print line.split()
```

Output:

```
['Which of the following has more fire resisting characteristics?\n(A) Marble \n(B) Lime stone \n(C) Compact sand stone \n(D) Granite','The rocks which are formed due to cooling of magma at a considerable depth from earth's surface are called \n(A) Plutonic rocks \n(B) Hypabyssal rocks \n(C) Volcanic rocks \n(D) Igneous rocks']
```

Comment: Do you **have to** use regex for this task ? I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: #then how to do this plz give me idea 
I have this type of questions format which i will put in a file to make quiz app

Comment: What's the output you are looking to get ?

Comment: I have given output which i need

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
^Question[^\d\r\n]+
(?P<nr>\d+)\s+
(?P<block>[\s\S]+?)(?=^Answer|\Z)
```

with the `verbose` and `multiline` flag, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vYcfBF/2/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^Question[^\d\r\n]+
    (?P<nr>\d+)\s+
    (?P<block>[\s\S]+?)(?=^$|\Z)''', re.M | re.X)

for m in rx.finditer(your_data_as_string_here):
    print(m.group('nr'), m.group('block'))
```

Comment: can you plz make my question in txt file and give output using full code as i have given output

Comment: You code doesn't work (look at `match` in your loop). Plus, when fixed, the output is not the output required by the OP when I test locally.

Answer (score 1):

This extracts the file line by line and stores it in an array.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

If you want to get rid of the line break (if that’s want you want) you can just extract the last character from each line.

```
for i in range(content):
    content[i] = content[i][:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
This question works if your schema is always the same, meaning...
Question Number
Question
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer N
...
Good answer.

It doesn't care the number of answer you can have.
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   Opening your text file.
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        #   You're getting a list of lines out of it.
        lines = f.readlines()

    #   You want to split your text into blocks.
    #   You know that each blocks are separated by double '\n'.
    #   First, you join all the lines and then, resplit it using the
    #   token you identified.
    lines = ''.join(lines).split('\n\n')

    #   Here, we use the index to change the item in-place.
    for index in range(len(lines)):
        #   First : lines[index].split('\n')[1:-1]
        #   It will split the line using the inner '\n', and strip out
        #   The header, and the answer of your question.
        #   Then, rejoin using the '\n' that has been stripped by split.
        lines[index] = '\n'.join( lines[index].split('\n')[1:-1] )

    #   What stays is what you asked.
    for line in lines:
        print(type(line))
        print(line, end='\n\n')
    # <class 'str'>
    # Which of the following has more fire resisting characteristics? 
    # (A) Marble 
    # (B) Lime stone 
    # (C) Compact sand stone 
    # (D) Granite 

    # <class 'str'>
    # The rocks which are formed due to cooling of magma at a considerable depth from earth's surface are called 
    # (A) Plutonic rocks 
    # (B) Hypabyssal rocks 
    # (C) Volcanic rocks 
    # (D) Igneous rocks 

    # <class 'str'>
    # Plywood has the advantage of 
    # (A) Greater tensile strength in longer direction 
    # (B) Greater tensile strength in shorter direction 
    # (C) Same tensile strength in all directions 
    # (D) None of the above
```

If you have a **strict** schema, meaning the same schema as I have shown before AND you **strictly** always have 4 possibilities, you can do...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   Opening your text file.
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        #   You're getting a list of lines out of it.
        lines = f.readlines()

    #   Create an empty list to store our result.
    my_lines = []
    for index in range(1, len(lines), 8):
        #   Since we exactly know where each line will be, we
        #   jump from blocks to blocks keeping only the first line of interest
        #   as our index.
        #   Plus, as the number of lines needed will always be the same, only
        #   keep a fixed amount of line, then join them all.
        my_lines.append( ''.join(lines[index : index+5]) )

    for line in my_lines:
        print(line)
    # Which of the following has more fire resisting characteristics? 
    # (A) Marble 
    # (B) Lime stone 
    # (C) Compact sand stone 
    # (D) Granite 

    # The rocks which are formed due to cooling of magma at a considerable depth from earth's surface are called 
    # (A) Plutonic rocks 
    # (B) Hypabyssal rocks 
    # (C) Volcanic rocks 
    # (D) Igneous rocks 

    # Plywood has the advantage of 
    # (A) Greater tensile strength in longer direction 
    # (B) Greater tensile strength in shorter direction 
    # (C) Same tensile strength in all directions 
    # (D) None of the above
```

Comment: i want everything between question number and answer option

Comment: @SauravNiroula And my answer gives you that.

Comment: at last line answer: options is still coming

Comment: @SauravNiroula It worked I just missed a line in my copy/paste. Have you even tried the code I did for you ? :/